# approve mechanism azure apim policies

Tags: azure, powershell, continuous-integration, pipeline

In *azure api*-->*Inbound Processing*-->*Policies*

Some of our developers changing these policies and we have no LOG or approval (PR) mechanism.
We want to a Pull request or a similar mechanism to that area.
If any developer changes policies, It should be approved before going live.

Can you give me some Keywords or information if possible.
I don't know how to search for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can establish [CI/CD for API Management using Azure Resource Manager templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/api-management/devops-api-development-templates).

> - After API developers have finished developing and testing an API, and have generated the API templates, they can submit a pull request
>   to merge the changes to the publisher repository.
> - API publishers can validate the pull request and make sure the changes are safe and compliant. For example, they can check if only
>   HTTPS is allowed to communicate with the API. Most validations can be
>   automated as a step in the CI/CD pipeline.
> - Once the changes are approved and merged successfully, API publishers can choose to deploy them to the Production instance either
>   on schedule or on demand. The deployment of the templates can be
>   automated using [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/Azure/apimanagement-devops-samples), [Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines), [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-powershell),
>   [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-cli), or other tools.

[Azure API Management DevOps Resource Kit](https://github.com/Azure/azure-api-management-devops-resource-kit) is a great place to start with.

[image: Diagram that illustrates DevOps with API Management]